# Can I handle the killing of my windows process through the Task Manager?

Tags: windows, process

I have a windows C++ application (app.exe). When the app is closed, I need to perform some cleanup tasks specific to my application. What happens when this process (app.exe) is killed through the Task Manager. Assuming that the application is still responsive, can I somehow handle this situation in my app.exe?

I am looking for something similar to how `kill <pid>` in Linux will send the SIGTERM signal to the process indicated by pid. I could then register my own signal handler for SIGTERM and perform the cleanup.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two ways to kill application in Task Manager.

- Killing through *Applications* tab would roughly be equivalent of `SIGTERM`. Application may intercept it and do more processing, since it's basically sending a "close window" message. Message to catch is `WM_CLOSE`.
- Killing through *Processes* tab would roughly be equivalent of `SIGKILL`. There is nothing you can do to intercept that, short of monitoring user's actions in Task Manager's listbox and End Process button, or having a watchdog process that will see when the first one is killed.

Alternatively, design the application in a way that does not require cleanup, or in a way that it will perform cleanup at startup.

Comment: Unfortunately, can't re-design the app. Its a 10 year old legacy app with several thousand lines of code.

Comment: Note, googlers: there's no `WM_CLOSE` in a console app, though. There you'd need to call `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` for registering your handler to process `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` for closing (i.e. "SIGTERM").

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need another PID that is monitoring the PID of your app.exe and does the necessary work at the time.

Comment: Basically a Watch Dog app, which will handle such scnearios

Answer (score 0):

That depends, if the user chooses to "End Task" your application you will be notified and you can handle it [see this.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/CloseCheck.aspx?display=Print)

but if the user chooses to end the process, you have no way to handle it in your application. the easiest way would be a second process or you can inject into process manager and hook the TerminateProcess API.