# Do something if process is terminated

Tags: python, process, exit

If a process is running and for example the user accidentally terminates via the Task Manager or the machine reboots (thus forcefully terminating processes), how can I register such an event that the process will execute some task before completely terminating?

What I've tried unsuccessfully is:

```
from signal import signal
from signal import SIGTERM

def foo():
    print('hello world')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    signal(SIGTERM, foo)
    while True:
        pass
```

I'll run this from the command line, then navigate to task manager and end the task but `foo` is never called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answer to [Can I handle the killing of my windows process through the Task Manager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527450/can-i-handle-the-killing-of-my-windows-process-through-the-task-manager) - it seems like the task manager kills processes using an unmaskable signal (equivalent to Linux's `SIGKILL`). This means that you cannot catch it.

There are [other signals you can catch in Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html), like `SIGBREAK`, `SIGCHLD`, `CTRL_C_EVENT` and `CTRL_BREAK_EVENT`, but I guess the task manager does not use any of those for terminating a process.